# WebPack devServer - localhost refused to connect

Tags: windows, webpack, server, localhost, webpack-dev-server

I have configured WebPack for my application and added webpack-dev-server. It compiles successfully after running and gives me "Project is running at http://localhost:9000/". However, when I try to open it in my browser I get a "This site can't be reached" page with the following error:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any fix suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Snippets from my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start:dev": "webpack-dev-server"
```

```
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
```

Snippet from my webpack.config.js file:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who might have the same issue, I seem to have found a solution shortly after posting this question. Here it is: [link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1347#issuecomment-407008054).

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO. If the link dies, so does the answer. Please translate the relevant information here.

Comment: I don't think it's really a solution but a hack. a solution IMO will explain why the issue happens and why this is the right fix. In my case it worked, the solution was to use `--localIp --host 0.0.0.0`